# Regular expression for finding some words

Tags: regex, powershell

```
Full Text = "........ -B D:\ABC -C ........."
```

I want to get `D:\ABC` between `-B` and `-C`.

How can I get words using Regular expression?

Comment: Is there any requirement or format which should be between -B and -C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pattern with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<=-B)\s*(\S*)\s*(?=-C)`

Explanation:

`(?<=-B)` - positive lookbehind, to assert that what is preceeding is `-B`

`\s*` - zero or more of whitespace characters

`(\S*)` - zero or more non-whitespace characters, stored in capturing group - this is string that you want to get

`(?=-C)` - positive lookahead, to assert that what is after is `-C`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XLrWZh/2)

Comment: You might also omit the lookbehind and lookahead and just match -B and -C `-B\s*(\S*)\s*-C`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yeah, you're right. I used only lookarounds first, without capturing group, but current version doesn't need lookarounds :)

Comment: Yeah you can just remove them! Anyway +1

Comment: Lookaraouns are IMO more important when splitting/replacing due to the zerolength assertion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following sample:

```
if ($string -cmatch '\s-B\s*(.+?)\s*-C\s'){$sub = $matches[1]}
```

**Hypothesis**: there is no `-C` between `-B` and `-C` and only one `-B` and one `-C` in the correct order

Comment: @LotPings: Thank you, you are completely right! I have edited my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

presuming the following is true ...

- only ONE `-B`
- followed by only the wanted text
- followed by only ONE `-C`

...then this otta work >> `'^.+ -B (.+) -C .+$'` <<

what it does ...

- start of line
- one or more chars
- space, hyphen, B, space
- a capture group for everything after that and before the next pattern
- space, hyphen, C, space
- one or more characters
- end of line